# how can add i18n in js for internationalization

Tags: internationalization, seedstack

I have a control with jquery, when I do the one respecting the internationalization it considers it as a chain and do not do the translation, I think the way by which one declares the internationalization in js and differenet of html

this is my code js:

```
       $("#borne").attr("placeholder", "{{ 'key.borne.vide' | localize }}");
```

Any idea please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using [W20-framework](https://w20-framework.github.io/) for the front of your application. If so, a [localize function](https://w20-framework.github.io/jsdoc/#/core/w20CoreCulture.filter:localize) is provided out-of-the-box by this framework (in angular CultureService).

This function should able you to translate your messages in the GUI. Be sure to add a dependency on 'CultureService' in your angular module / controler.